# Overlaying functions with par(new=TRUE) having different axes with same ylimits

Tags: r, plot, par

I have been trying to overlay base R xyplots overtop barplots with the same ylim values.
Even using this dummy code:

```
data(mtcars)

barplot(mtcars$mpg,
        ylim=c(0,40))

par(new=TRUE,xaxt="s",yaxt="s",bty="n");plot(20,20,ylim=c(0,40),pch=c(16))
```

The end result has the y-axis askew, where the midpoint lines up at 20, but all the other values of the axis are further off as they are larger or smaller than 20.

[image]

Can anyone explain why this happens and how I can avoid it in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `yxas` argument for the `par` function.

From the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/par) for `xaxs` (which is the same as `yaxs` for the x axis):

> The style of axis interval calculation to be used for the x-axis.
> Possible values are "r", "i", "e", "s", "d".
> The styles are generally
> controlled by the range of data or xlim, if given.
>
> Style "r" (regular) first extends the data range by 4 percent at each end and then finds
> an axis with pretty labels that fits within the extended range.
>
> Style "i" (internal) just finds an axis with pretty labels that fits within
> the original data range.
>
> Style "s" (standard) finds an axis with
> pretty labels within which the original data range fits.
>
> Style "e"
> (extended) is like style "s", except that it is also ensures that
> there is room for plotting symbols within the bounding box.

Since we want to fit the axis, I gonna use the internal style:

```
data(mtcars)

barplot(mtcars$mpg,
        ylim=c(0,40))

par(new=TRUE,yaxs="i", xaxt="s",yaxt="s",bty="n");plot(20,20,ylim=c(0,40),pch=c(16))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! Works great!